# Automatically highlight current url (even when on /page/x)

Tags: javascript

I am trying to automate adding a 'current' class to a URL in the menu, and have succeeded mostly using this code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('a').each(function() {
    if ($(this).prop('href') == window.location.href) {
        $(this).addClass('current');
    }
});
});
```

What I would like though is for this to work on pagination, so if /page/x appears after the URL from the a href, it adds current. Currently it only highlights if the URL is exactly the same.

I've done a bit of searching around but can't seem to see how to do this.

I would appreciate some guidance very much. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You may `split()` your string by `/`and check for its base url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Give all your links that don't point to home some class...    

$(document).ready(function() {
        $('a.someClass').each(function() {
            if (window.location.href.indexOf($(this).prop('href')) != -1) {
                $('a.someClass').removeClass('current');
                $(this).addClass('current');
            }
        });
    });

    // A much simpler way to do the same will be
    var $a = $("a.someClass");
    $a.click(function() {
        if (window.location.href.indexOf($(this).prop('href')) != -1) {
            $a.removeClass('current');
            $(this).addClass('current');
        }
    });

    // If it still doesn't help,
    // just try to make a codepen/jsbin of your code along with html...
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply, however this causes the home url to be current always.

Comment: Essentially the top menu has say 5 categories, (Home www.myurl.com, Writing www.myurl.com/writing, Music www.myurl.com/music, etc). When you click on Writing or Music, you go to /writing or /music. Using original code, the respective one is highlighted with "current" class. Then when you go to page 2 of Music (www.myurl.com/music/page/2), the current class is removed from Music in the menu. With all the responses here, the current class remains on Music, but also is permanently on home (www.myurl.com). Hope that makes more sense as I'm not sure how to do a codepen.

Comment: I understood what you are trying to say now.... The work around is give a class to the a tags that you want to highlight leaving the a tag of home. And use the same class while selecting with jquery. Also remove the class 'current' from every element before adding it to a new one. If the description is not clear, i'll send you the code after a couple of hours...

Comment: Hi Anshul thanks so much for replying. I would appreciate help with the code as I'm not too sure exactly how to implement this. Thanks again in advance.

Comment: @Joseph Actually what happens is, when you use the .each() method, all your a tags are scanned one by one. One of your a tags must be containing link to the home url right? so when the .each() method reaches this a, it makes it current... and thats why your home url is always current...

Comment: That's correct, the home link contains the home url.

Comment: Did my code work then? Just give a class to evry link except for home link and try the code above...

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do things in pure javascript but you might simplify it with jQuery. (I felt lazy about including it)

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for(var i = 0;i< links.length; i++)
{       
    if(links[i].pathname == document.location.pathname)
    {
        links[i].classList.add("current");
    }
}
```

The previous version contained checks that were redundant.

Comment: I can't add any snippets because using `document.location.pathname` is forbidden there I guess.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply, however this causes the home url to be current always.

Comment: Do you have an AJAX triggered page? can you debug the code with `console.log()` ?